# How many objects are created in the memory runtime?

Tags: java, oop

I'm studying for 1z0-803 Java certificate exam at the moment. We have to find out, how many instances of `MarkList` are created in this application:

```
public class MarkList {
   int num;

   public static void graceMarks(MarkList obj4) {
       obj4.num += 10;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();
       MarkList obj2 = obj1;            
       obj2.num = 60;
       graceMarks(obj2);
    }
}
```

A friend of mine said that in this question the answer is two objects. I think it's only one (`obj1`), though I may be wrong since I'm new with Java but have some experience with C#.

Comment: Created by who? `args` is also an object, but is that relevant? And there are a lot more objects created in the background.

Comment: @Tom It asks for MarkList objects

Comment: @john That's the sort of information you should include in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Only one* instance of MarkList is created.

For to find out how many objects are created you can use this procedure:

- search for any call of an constructor (looks like `new MarkList(...)`). You can use an IDE like eclipse to **find all references**.
- check how often the code containing the constructor is called (could be inside of a **loop** or inside of a method that gets **called several times**).
- putting the once created objects into different variables, or handing them over from one method to another will not create additional instances => irrelevant

---

However *thousands* of other instances are created (in my Oracle JDK 1.8).

- `MarkList.class` is created
- `String[] args` is created
- `MarkList obj1` is created
- Many, many runtime objects (like `Thread.currentThread()` are created)

Use a profiler, run your code and count the objects. But keep in mind, that that result will be quite dependent on your JVM implementation.

[image: VisualVM profiling results]

Answer (score 9):

The answer is one object.
`MarkList obj1 = new MarkList();` creates a new `MarkList` object, `MarkList obj2 = obj1;` only creates a reference to `obj1` so both point to the exact same object.
All the other code is just boilerplate and does not create objects.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about this question. This exam question has a typo if you randomly search online. Many websites mentioned obj3 but it wasn't there. Your friend might read from a source that contains a typo.